# How did js put response in callback function formal parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am bit new to js promises i am trying to write promise with callbacks 
here is my code

```
 var consoleFunction = function(data){
    console.log(data);
 }

$.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", consoleFunction);
```

This is working fine my question is how javascript put the response from api into callback parameter of consoleFunction?
And i write another function

```
var consoleFunction2 = function(data){
    console.log(data);
 }
```

then i try

```
$.get("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", consoleFunction, consoleFunction2);
```

but this is not working why?

Comment: I don't think you understand what you're doing... Read the jQuery documentation for [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and it explains what to pass and what it gets back.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, What OP is trying to ask is how does the response is being passed as an argument in the callback function ?

Comment: jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] ) and you cannot add consoleFunction2 as parameter.

Comment: @RayonDabre - you don't use callbacks with promises. I mean, you can, but what in the world would be the point?

Comment: I only want to implement promises from the basic level to high level so that i can understand how promises works. @Rayon Dabre you understand my question well.

Answer (score 0):

***jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success ] [, dataType ] )***

you cannot add consoleFunction2 as parameter.

***success
Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds. Required if dataType is provided, but you can use null or jQuery.noop as a placeholder***

function consoleFunction1(data) and data is callback success(PalinObject data)'s data

$.get( "abc.com", consoleFunction1(data)).fail(consoleFunction2(data));

Comment: Thanks now i have some clarity in that.